# Why the first argument of signal handler passed by register ax instead of di?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, x86

Based on the [Registers on entry](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/v5.0/arch/x86/entry/entry_64.S#LL130C4-L130C13) description, the first argument sig of [signal handler](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/sigaction.2.html) should be passed by the di(rdi) register, however I see the first argument sig passing to signal handler is assigned to the register `regs->ax` by code `regs->ax = (unsigned long)sig` instead of the expected di from the code below, I want to know why the first argument of signal handler passed by register ax instead of di described in the [Registers on entry](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/v5.0/arch/x86/entry/entry_64.S#LL130C4-L130C13)?

The code below from the [__setup_frame()](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/v5.0/arch/x86/kernel/signal.c#L366) of the signal.c.

```c
static int
__setup_frame(int sig, struct k_sigaction *ka, sigset_t *set,
          struct pt_regs *regs)
{
    struct sigframe __user *frame;
    void __user *restorer;
    int err = 0;
    void __user *fpstate = NULL;

    frame = get_sigframe(ka, regs, sizeof(*frame), &fpstate);

    if (!access_ok(VERIFY_WRITE, frame, sizeof(*frame)))
        return -EFAULT;

    if (__put_user(sig, &frame->sig))
        return -EFAULT;

    if (setup_sigcontext(&frame->sc, fpstate, regs, set->sig[0]))
        return -EFAULT;

    if (_NSIG_WORDS > 1) {
        if (__copy_to_user(&frame->extramask, &set->sig[1],
                   sizeof(frame->extramask)))
            return -EFAULT;
    }

    if (current->mm->context.vdso)
        restorer = VDSO32_SYMBOL(current->mm->context.vdso, sigreturn);
    else
        restorer = &frame->retcode;
    if (ka->sa.sa_flags & SA_RESTORER)
        restorer = ka->sa.sa_restorer;

    /* Set up to return from userspace.  */
    err |= __put_user(restorer, &frame->pretcode);

    /*
     * This is popl %eax ; movl $__NR_sigreturn, %eax ; int $0x80
     *
     * WE DO NOT USE IT ANY MORE! It's only left here for historical
     * reasons and because gdb uses it as a signature to notice
     * signal handler stack frames.
     */
    err |= __put_user(*((u64 *)&retcode), (u64 *)frame->retcode);

    if (err)
        return -EFAULT;

    /* Set up registers for signal handler */
    regs->sp = (unsigned long)frame;
    regs->ip = (unsigned long)ka->sa.sa_handler;
    regs->ax = (unsigned long)sig;
    regs->dx = 0;
    regs->cx = 0;

    regs->ds = __USER_DS;
    regs->es = __USER_DS;
    regs->ss = __USER_DS;
    regs->cs = __USER_CS;

    return 0;
}

static int __setup_rt_frame(int sig, struct k_sigaction *ka, siginfo_t *info,
                sigset_t *set, struct pt_regs *regs)
{
    struct rt_sigframe __user *frame;
    void __user *restorer;
    int err = 0;
    void __user *fpstate = NULL;

    frame = get_sigframe(ka, regs, sizeof(*frame), &fpstate);

    if (!access_ok(VERIFY_WRITE, frame, sizeof(*frame)))
        return -EFAULT;

    put_user_try {
        put_user_ex(sig, &frame->sig);
        put_user_ex(&frame->info, &frame->pinfo);
        put_user_ex(&frame->uc, &frame->puc);
        err |= copy_siginfo_to_user(&frame->info, info);

        /* Create the ucontext.  */
        if (cpu_has_xsave)
            put_user_ex(UC_FP_XSTATE, &frame->uc.uc_flags);
        else
            put_user_ex(0, &frame->uc.uc_flags);
        put_user_ex(0, &frame->uc.uc_link);
        put_user_ex(current->sas_ss_sp, &frame->uc.uc_stack.ss_sp);
        put_user_ex(sas_ss_flags(regs->sp),
                &frame->uc.uc_stack.ss_flags);
        put_user_ex(current->sas_ss_size, &frame->uc.uc_stack.ss_size);
        err |= setup_sigcontext(&frame->uc.uc_mcontext, fpstate,
                    regs, set->sig[0]);
        err |= __copy_to_user(&frame->uc.uc_sigmask, set, sizeof(*set));

        /* Set up to return from userspace.  */
        restorer = VDSO32_SYMBOL(current->mm->context.vdso, rt_sigreturn);
        if (ka->sa.sa_flags & SA_RESTORER)
            restorer = ka->sa.sa_restorer;
        put_user_ex(restorer, &frame->pretcode);

        /*
         * This is movl $__NR_rt_sigreturn, %ax ; int $0x80
         *
         * WE DO NOT USE IT ANY MORE! It's only left here for historical
         * reasons and because gdb uses it as a signature to notice
         * signal handler stack frames.
         */
        put_user_ex(*((u64 *)&rt_retcode), (u64 *)frame->retcode);
    } put_user_catch(err);

    if (err)
        return -EFAULT;

    /* Set up registers for signal handler */
    regs->sp = (unsigned long)frame;
    regs->ip = (unsigned long)ka->sa.sa_handler;
    regs->ax = (unsigned long)sig;
    regs->dx = (unsigned long)&frame->info;
    regs->cx = (unsigned long)&frame->uc;

    regs->ds = __USER_DS;
    regs->es = __USER_DS;
    regs->ss = __USER_DS;
    regs->cs = __USER_CS;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: This is the code for a 32-bit process so the argument to the signal handler is actually passed on the stack (your link showing rdi is for 64-bit code).  This is done above with `__put_user(sig, &frame->sig)`, and that's where the handler will get it from.   Why it's also in eax, I don't know.

Comment: @NateEldredge
Thank you Nate ,  for the 64 bit code ,I seems kernel put the sig to the frame->arg0 by the  code "err  = __put_user(sig, &frame->arg0);" from (https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/v5.0/arch/ia64/kernel/signal.c#L272), however in my case , I have the handler defined in the link here (https://github.com/percona/percona-server/blob/release-5.7.41-44/sql/signal_handler.cc#L63) ,  it seems  the handler doesn't  try to get the  sig from the frame, so how the handler get the sig from ? doesn't it try to get it from the rdi register?

Comment: ia64 is Itanium, not x86-64, so that's the wrong file to be looking at.  The x86-64 frame setup code is in the same file `arch/x86/kernel/signal.c` but further down, conditional on `!CONFIG_X86_32`.  [Here](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/v5.0/arch/x86/kernel/signal.c#L500) you can see that it does indeed put the signal number in `rdi`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your snippet is the 32-bit version of the signal code.  If you look [further up](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/1c163f4c7b3f621efff9b28a47abb36f7378d783/arch/x86/kernel/signal.c#L291) you will see it is under `#ifdef CONFIG_X86_32`.  (The references to `int 0x80` are also a tipoff as this is the system call mechanism for x86-32, whereas x86-64 uses `syscall`.)

In 32-bit x86 code, parameters are passed on the stack, so the actual passing of the signal number is done by

```
    if (__put_user(sig, &frame->sig))
        return -EFAULT;
```

If you look at the [definition of `struct sigframe`](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/1c163f4c7b3f621efff9b28a47abb36f7378d783/arch/x86/include/asm/sigframe.h#L25) (which has been #defined to `struct sigframe_ia32`), you will see that `sig` is the second element, following `pretcode`.  The stack pointer will point to the `struct sigframe`, so the handler will see the return address as the top element of its stack, and the `sig` argument as the second element, right where the first argument belongs.

I don't know why the signal number is also placed in `eax`.  As you say, an ordinary signal handler written in C would just ignore the contents of `eax`, so `regs->ax = (unsigned long)sig` looks useless and redundant.  Maybe it's an alternative convention for handlers written in assembly, or is for some other sort of compatibility, or is just a mistake.

For x86-64 (aka x86 long mode), look [further down in this file](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/1c163f4c7b3f621efff9b28a47abb36f7378d783/arch/x86/kernel/signal.c#LL500C2-L500C17), below the `#else`.  There you will see that `__setup_rt_frame` does `regs->di = sig;` so that the signal argument is indeed in `rdi` as it should be.

Comment: `__attribute__((regparm(1)))` does pass the first arg in EAX and the rest on the stack.  Perhaps that was part of the ABI at some point, or in a possible design that never got used.

Comment: @PeterCordes: Could be.  Though a `regparm(1)` signal handler would then not be able to properly use a siginfo argument.  I also wondered if it might be some relic of the "system call return value in eax" principle, treating entry to the signal handler as a system call return (which in fact it is).

Comment: Oh right.  Maybe someone realized that problem after writing the code to put the first arg in EAX, and it never got removed?  With the current ABI, if you wanted to have your 32-bit signal handler use EAX instead of the first stack arg to read the signal number and still access other stuff, you'd need `__attribute__((regparm(1))) void handler(int sig, int DUMMY, siginfo_t *info, void *ucontext)`.  Or maybe my wild guess about motivations for that code is just wrong.  The system-call "return value" thought occurred to me, too.